# Transparency of labels within parent form disappears (turns grey) after child form is initiated within the parent form

Tags: c#

[image: Menu form (parent form)]
[image: randomFacts form (child form)]

The menu form is an Mdi parent of the randomFacts form, which is the child form.

Whenever I click the quiz button on the menu form, the following code is executed (items are initially hidden on the menu form but are then shown upon clicking the quiz button):

```
private void btn1Quiz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Start quiz?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            foreach (Form f in OwnedForms)
            {
                f.Hide();
            }

            randomFacts.Hide();
            randomFacts.Refresh();
            ShowAll(); // shows quiz items
            SetTransparency();
        }
    }

private void ShowAll()
    {
        labelQuestion.Show();
        labelQuestionNumber.Show();
        labelScore.Show();
        labelScore.Text = "Score: 0";
        labelTheme.Show();
        btnOption1.Show();
        btnOption2.Show();
        btnOption3.Show();
        btnOption4.Show();
        pictureBox1.Show();

        SetTransparency();
        Image background = new Bitmap("andromeda.jpg");
        this.BackgroundImage = null;
        this.BackgroundImage = background;
    }
private void SetTransparency()
        {
            labelQuestion.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            labelTheme.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            labelQuestionNumber.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            labelScore.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        }
```

However, if I click the Facts button first when I load the menu form, and the following code is executed, and then click the quiz button to load the quiz items, the quiz labels lose their transparency and they have a grey background.

```
private void btn2Facts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // menu form is a parent, randomFacts is a child.
        this.IsMdiContainer = true;
        randomFacts.MdiParent = this;

        HideAll();
        randomFacts.Show();
        randomFacts.Location = new Point(200, 10);
        randomFacts.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    }
```

[image: Appearance of labels in menu form if I load randomFacts form first]

I will give more code if necessary. How do I solve this?

Comment: You should add SetTransparency in the Facts button click. Why is transparency not set by default on initialization?

Comment: Thanks, I'll put that method in the facts button click method. I have set transparency both in the properties window and in the form initialization method.